# cvShowImage my image color was changed

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I got strange condition when showing my video using cvShowImage or even when appending image data on IPLImage, I'm not quite sure.

The image/frame should be like this:

[image: desired image]

but the imaged was displayed like this:

[image: image error]

As you can see, some parts of frame are also moved to the leftside.

Is there anyone encounter similar issue?

```
while(1){
    m_IPLimg1 = m_pFrameCapture->GrabOneFrame();
    if(m_IPLimg1 == NULL) break;// no more frames, exit the loop
    cvFlip(m_IPLimg2, NULL, 0 );

    cvShowImage("Original Video", m_IPLimg1);
    cvShowImage("GMM Result Video", m_IPLimg2);

    char c = cvWaitKey(20);
    if (c==27) break;
}
```

Really thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the sections of code where you declare the image, capture, and show it?

Comment: @mevatron: Hi, I've updated my question with code.

Comment: What is `m_IPLimg2` ? It's not being declared in the code. Also, what OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: @karlphillip : Hi Karl, sorry I didn't provide entire code. IPLimg2 is IPLImg for GMM post-processing, in other word it would have background substraction result. Anyway I got the solution, I need to format my .avi first using mencoder , since the video above I generated from image sequence, the codec seems broken. Thanks for your response however.

Comment: Super! Add this as an answer to let others know how you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I need to format my .avi first using [mencoder](http://nashruddin.com/How_to_Play_AVI_Files_with_OpenCV) , since the video above I generated from image sequence, the codec seems broken. Thanks for all responses however.

Comment: Be sure to accept your answer so the question is no longer open.[Here's some info about accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to flip `m_IPLimg2` in place but are not setting its contents first. Try:

```
cvFlip(m_IPLimg1, m_IPLimg2, 0 );
```

This will flip m_IPLimg1 and place the results into m_IPLimg2.

Comment: I got the solution, I need to format my .avi first using mencoder , since the video above I generated from image sequence, the codec seems broken. Thanks for your response however.